# Deleting an item from the business layer

Tags: c#

Is there any logic that should go in deleting a row in the database from the business layer? For example, should I check if the object has an `id > 0` before proceeding with delete?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Delete a task
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="task">Task object to be deleted</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int Delete(Task task)
    {
        return _taskData.Delete(task);
    }
```

Comment: sometimes yes, sometimes no.

Comment: I am confused.  As you using 'System.Threading.Task' as your parameter or did you create a custom class called `Task`?  If you made a custom class called `Task` you may want to think of a different name...

Comment: Custom class named Task. It's a task management system. What other name would be good? Maybe prefix it with something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on your usage of delete normally responsibility of business layer is to apply some business logic.

so if you want to apply some checks or perform some authentication or perform some business sensitive operation. that should be done in Business layer.

apart from that if only Business layer has access to Database layer then you have to go from business layer.

again everything depends on your existing architecture and your usage requirement.

Comment: Sooo.... posting "depends" isn't an answer. This is an opinion writeup, on a very broad and opinion-soliciting question. At *best*, you could comment and ask for clarification.

Comment: As far as validating, should I make sure that there is a valid id before deleting?

Comment: i don't think so you need to do that on business layer. let database layer handle that.it comes under database layer's responsibility to  check  this kind of stuff.